# Repeated interfaces in component diagrams

Tags: interface, components, uml, visual-paradigm

When modelling component diagrams in UML2, is it permissable to repeat an interface on a component if it makes it easier to connect components? Such as below:

[image: repeated interfaces okay?]

Any guidance would be most helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any block that you see on the UML diagram, is merely a view of an object, that can have many views. How you are placing and cloning them is up to your convenience.

Only when creating new interfaces of the same name, be sure that you are creating new views of the same object (interface in your case). If you'll simply copypast your interface'in VP UML, you'll simply clone it.

What is interesting, later, on the class diagram you will have interfaces shown as special class blocks, not as here. And these will be also merely other views of the same interfaces you see now on your component diagram. At least, it is a good style to do it so.

***So, yes, you can. It is the default behaviour.***

Comment: Much appreciated. I thought so but my initial research did not reveal any examples. Thanks a lot.

Comment: With VP-UML it is much more difficult to make a copy that is REALLY another object, not only another view of the same object :-).

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you for taking the time to explain.

Comment: I also understand that interfaces in UML are not conceptually the same as Java's, but I could theoretically implement this system using Java interfaces therefore is my use of Java interfaces to show a relationship permissiable? I tend to get bogged down in semantics, maybe I'm overcomplicating it for myself. Thanks.

Comment: No, you have done it OK. On the class diagram you will have interfaces shown as special class blocks, not as here. As for component diagram, you can decide now already what classes shall you send by these connections between components. Oh, and +1 for a good question :-). Sorry for my forgetfullness

Comment: Thank you. No apology necessary, you have actually been exceedingly helpful, Gangnus.

Comment: Thank you. And notice, that interfaces, shown as blocks in class diagrams *are the same interfaces* that are shown as circles here.